# How hadoop command works with javac

Tags: java, linux, shell, hadoop, javac

I was reading Apache [mapreduce tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0)

I was able to run the example and get the desired result. However, I am not able to understand how it is asked that we should run following to compile the Java file.

> $ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java

I went through the [hapdoop command details](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#fs). It partitioned all hadoop switches under General options, User commands and Administrator commands. I didnt found where above `javac` command given in hadoop command page.

**Q**. In fact actually I didnt get how above command works. I mean we usually specify hyphen-prefixed options in front of the commands. However this above command asks to run javac in a way that I never saw before. I usually used to compile java files directly by `javac filename.java`. Why here it is asked to not do this way?

**Q**. Also there is `.Main` in `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` in the given command. What does this mean?

**I know I must be missing something very basic understanding about how commands works in general. Also I am very new to linux, so may be thats the reason for not understanding this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javac is used for compiling your java code. If you notice the WordCount example, there are lot of import statements which require you to add the corresponding jars in the classpath.

when you run `hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java`, hadoop would have already loaded all these dependent jar for compiling your program. You can test it by running javac WordCount.java and compiler would throw `cannot find symbol` error if you don't already have these required jar in your classpath

Comment: so `bin/hadoop` adds those dependancies automatically thats the difference? If yes, where these dependencies are defined. I mean which file `hadoop` command refers to find and load the dependencies? Some xml must be there or is it defined inside hadoop command script?

Comment: yes. check the file hadoop in bin directory which call the hadoop-config.sh in the libexec dir which loads the jars

Comment: then how we can imitate the dependency loading through `hadoop.sh` and `hadoop_config.sh` when running the application in the eclipse. I have added all JARs that are required in the eclipse. Now eclipse does not give any compile time error but running application gives runtime error `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/common/logging/LogFactory`. **Is it possible to make some configuration in eclipse so that it will call `Hadoop_config.sh` and load the desired dependencies?** In fact is this the right way? or **is there any other standard eclipse-hadoop setup?**

Comment: no its not. check this link http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

Answer (score 1):

With the Hadoop, you can set the compiler that you want it to use for compiling your code.

com.sun.tools.javac.Main is the programmatic interface for the Java Programming Language

When you execute `bin/hadoop` , with the first parameter as `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` and second parameter as `WordCount.java`, 
it uses the `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` to compile `WordCount.java`

[More on `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/tools/javac/Main.java.html)

Comment: so will it be same as `javac wordCount.java`?

Comment: Yes, In theory it is. Take a look at this - http://janzhou.org/post/hadoop-compile-program/